# How to use LeaderLine with Svelte?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, svelte, rollupjs

I'm new to [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) and I'm trying to use [LeaderLine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leader-line) with a Svelte application. I managed to import it with `import LeaderLine from 'leader-line';`, but unfortunately the example which is given on the package page doesn't work:

```
<script>
  import LeaderLine from 'leader-line';

  new LeaderLine(
    document.getElementById('start'),
    document.getElementById('end')
  );    
</script>

<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="end">end</div>
```

In the browser console I'm getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: start and end are required.`

I think it's because of the usage of `getElementById`, what if I'm right we normally don't want to do in Svelte. So I want to ask you guys if you have an idea how to get LeaderLine + Svelte running together. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the LeaderLine initialization in [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount). The code in the script tag runs before the component has been added to the DOM, so `document.getElementById('start')` returns null. `onMount` will run after the component has been added to the DOM.

```html
<script>
  import LeaderLine from 'leader-line';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  onMount(() => {
    new LeaderLine(
      document.getElementById('start'),
      document.getElementById('end')
    );
  });
</script>
```

While you can use getElementId in Svelte, it would be Svelte-ier to bind to the start and end elements.

```
<script>
  import LeaderLine from 'leader-line';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let start, end;
  onMount(() => {
    new LeaderLine(start, end);
  });
</script>

<div bind:this={start}>start</div>
<div bind:this={end}>end</div>
```

Also, I assume you figured this out if you got the "start and end are required" error, but I had to use [@rollup/plugin-legacy](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/legacy) with the following Rollup configuration to build the app since leader-line doesn't export anything.

```js
export default {
  // ... other config
  plugins: [
    // ... other plugins
    legacy({ 'node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js': 'LeaderLine' }),
  ]
};
```